# dpkg: error processing package xmail (--configure):

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

when I do `sudo apt-get install...`,I met error as follows:

```
Setting up xmail (1.27-1.2) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/aliasdomain.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/aliases.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/ctrl.ipmap.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/ctrlaccounts.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/domains.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/extaliases.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/filters.in.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/filters.out.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/filters.post-data.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/filters.post-rcpt.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/filters.pre-data.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/finger.ipmap.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/mailusers.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/pop3.ipmap.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/pop3links.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/server.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtp.ipmap.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtp.ipprop.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtpauth.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtpextauth.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtpfwd.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtpgw.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/smtprelay.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/spam-address.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/spammers.tab': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/xmail/userdef.tab': File exists
dpkg: error processing package xmail (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

would anyone be very kind to tell me why? Thank you very much!

I want to install caffe on my ubuntu 14.04,and when I do `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler`,I met errors.

Comment: 'Why' is easy: "File exists" usually means that this is not your first attempt, and you failed to clean up a previous (perhaps failed) try.

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you want, and *the whole story* of what you did.